# how do I filter special charactors while pursing?

Tags: php

hi I am doing html pursing with php dom document
I am getting some special charators in my result how do I filter the same??

```
foreach ($fdats as $fdat)
{
    foreach($fdat->getElementsByTagName('a') as $mdat)
    {
                $comb[] = trim($mdat->nodeValue);
    }

}
```

and the HTML is something like this

```
<div class="content1" id="user" style="width: 47%; margin-right: 20px;">
<div class="ad  first_row">
<p class="ad" style="width: 70%;">
<a href="/site/users"><img class="dynamic-icon">&nbsp; James</a>
</p>
```

the out put is `Â James`, and how do I get rid of `Â`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are called html entities. you can convert them into their true form using the following function:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

also, `&nbsp;` converts to ascii code 160, which is a double byte character. this is why it is showing up as a weird character. you may need to use iconv() function if you want to strip double byte characters.

$text = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text);

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Â_` is an UTF-8 materialization. The `&nbsp;` becomes the unicode character `U+00A0` when extracted via DOM methods.

You can probably use `utf8_decode()` before the `trim()` to get rid of it. <s>That should convert it into a regular space.</s> Hmm, maybe not. Latin-1 has it's own nbsp at 0xA0. So better use a regex `/\s/U` might cover it.